# Redirect all .jpg but allow image embed

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this code in my .htacess file, and does the redirection of `http://www.example.com/wp-content/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/063.jpg` to `www.example.com/wp-content/show-image.php?path=http://www.example.com/wp-content/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/063.jpg`

Somehow it works, and it won't redirect `www.example.com/wp-content/show-image.php?path=http://www.example.com/wp-content/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/063.jpg` as well.

```
 RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)\.(jpe?g|png) http://www.example.com/wp-content/show-image.php?path=http://www.example.com/wp-content/$1.jpg [R=301,NC,L]
```

the problem is that it will redirect images in `<img src=""/>` as well. I want `<img src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/063.jpg" />` to be able to load, not to be redirected.

any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to really do this, without modifying the URL in some way, is to check the HTTP Referer. The Referer is not set for a direct request, but is set (to your domain) when a request comes from the embedded `src` attribute.

However, this is prone to error and is not recommended in a professional environment. The browser might be configured to not send the Referer in the request anyway or it could even be faked.

Anyway, you can implement this by inserting a conditional check. ie. Only redirect when the Referer is not set to the expected host:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)\.(jpe?g|png) http://www.example.com/wp-content/show-image.php?path=http://www.example.com/wp-content/$1.jpg [R=301,NC,L]
```

The `!` prefix negates the *CondPattern*.

However, that will also prevent Googlebot etc. seeing your image URLs, unless you include further exceptions. **UPDATE:** And it is usually recommended to allow empty `Referer` headers, but this will allow direct requests (but this is probably required for Google image search and the Googlebot, which does not send a `Referer` header when crawling) For example, you can try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !google
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.(jpe?g|png)$ http://www.example.com/wp-content/show-image.php?path=http://www.example.com/wp-content/$1.jpg [R=301,NC,L]
```

(Incidentally, you don't need to escape the dot in a character class in order to match a literal dot.)

This will block other sites from linking to your images directly (ie. hotlinking).

### Modify the URL:

Otherwise, you can change the URL of your embedded image in some way. eg. Append `?noredirect=1` to the end of the URL and check for this instead in your `.htaccess` condition:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^noredirect=1$
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, as the redirection works, but images will not show on the entire website - they won't load. so I guess that means it fails to allow them in <img src=""/> on my own website. how can they still load on my website?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the _scheme_ off the `HTTP_REFERER` check. It should be `!^http://www\.example\.com`, not `!^www\.example\.com`, as I previously had. This should be changed to your canonical scheme/host through which the site is being accessed. I've updated my answer.

Comment: great! that seems to work. but, when I come from an image, from Google image search, it will redirect, but the image won't load on the page, on my website. why? can you also please tell me how to allow Googlebot to see the images? what exception

Comment: the image embed should load on my website, when the page is opened, regardless off the referrer. if the page (`http://www.example.com/wp-content/show-image.php?path=`) is on my website, the image should load. the purpose of this redirection is to redirect .jpg, when a referrer is sending it directly to the image .jpg, but after the redirection the image should load on the page

Comment: I've updated my answer with some more exceptions to hopefully allow Referers from Google and the Googlebot. Note that this allows direct requests to your images, but this is unavoidable if you want to allow Google (and it is recommended best practise anyway in order to not frustrate some users). "...regardless off the referrer." - The only way you can determine whether the image is loaded "from your website" is to check the Referer header, to see that it came from your website. Your website is then the Referer.

Comment: Note that _after a redirection_, the HTTP Referer request header (sent by the browser) is still maintained. But in this case, the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ will not match.

Comment: thanks, but the image will still not load on the page

Comment: Make sure your browser cache is cleared - the 301 redirect is cached hard by the browser. (For this reason it is often easier to _test_ with 302 redirects.)

Comment: Check the `Referer` HTTP request header when these images are requested. What is the value?